# Get all the directory names after a symbolic link

Tags: shell-script

I have a list of Directories where I do have a Symbolic link Main. Now How I can extract all the directory names after the Symbolic link.

Ex:

```
Main -> 2021-07-06

2021-07-15

2021-07-25

2021-07-31

2021-08-01
```

How I can get the numbers after the **Main** till the end (2021-08-01) so that I get the dates from 2021-07-15 to 2021-08-01? All these are different directories.

Algorithm:

1. Get the Dates after the Sym link Main
2. Loop through the Dates fetched in the previous step
3. Execute the logic for each of the dates fetched

Example :

For all dates between 2021-07-15 to 2021-08-01

```
       Execute some code
```

[image]

Comment: Is 'Main' a symlink to '2021-07-06'? Or is it a symlink to some other directory, which contains '2021-07-06' and the other listed directories? In the second case, does `ls -1 /path/to/Main` provide the output you're looking for?

Comment: Main is a symlink to the Directory 2021-07-06. This 2021-07-06 directory in turn has many other directories.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `ls -l Main` and `ls -l Main/` so we can understand. Then, also show us your expected output. What kind of variable? A string? An array? What shell are you using? Bash? sh? Something else?

Comment: @terdon I am not bothered by the content inside the directory pointed by the Main. I just need to get the directory names after the Main ( In the example 2021-07-15 to 2021-08-01) and loop through this list of Dates to execute some logic.

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code. And anyway, what are the images showing? You show the output of an `ls -ltr` command, but there is no `Main` there. How is that connected to your question?

Answer (score 1):

To print the names of the directories that are listed in the directory linked by the `Main` symlink, in the `zsh` shell, you'd do:

```
print -rC1 -- Main/*(ND/:t)
```

Or if you mean that all those YYYY-MM-DD dirs and the `Main` symlink are in the same directory and you want to list the dirs that come after (in chronological, same as lexical order) the dir pointed to by `Main`:

```
zmodload zsh/stat || exit

stat -A min +link Main || exit

for date in ????-??-??(N/e['[[ $REPLY > $min ]]']); do
  some-logic with $date
done
```

The `bash` shell has no `stat` builtin nor glob qualifiers, but it does also have ksh's `[[ foo > bar ]]` operator and if your system has a `readlink` command, you could do:

```
min=$(readlink -v Main) || exit
for date in ????-??-??; do
  [ -d "$date" ] || continue
  [ -L "$date" ] && continue
  [[ "$date" > "$min" ]] || continue

  some-logic with "$date"
done
```

Comment: I am using bash shell. I need to fetch all the Dates from the Dir names after the Directory pointed by the Main.